# JPA & JDBC can coexist in DAO layer?

Tags: spring, jpa, jdbc

Is there any problem using both JDBC (JdbcTemplate) & JPA (EntityManager) in data access layer ?

I am planning to use JDBC to access the stored-procedures/routines.
These stored-procedures will be returning multiple cursors by joining multiple tables (which is not registered as JPA entities).

These JDBC actions are pure read-only.

I am not combining JPA & JDBC actions in the same transactions as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501230/combining-jpa-and-jdbc-actions-in-one-transaction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is okay for me . Use the right tools for the job . For example , if I want to do some report queries which the data are spanned over many different entities or want to use some powerful database features (eg window function , common table expression ) which are not supported or difficult to be achieved by JPA , I would prefer to use JDBC to issue native SQL directly to get the job done.

The architecture [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) also uses this idea which has two different separate models for updating information (command action) and reading information (query action) .For example , JPA can be used for command action while native JDBC is used for the query action.